# How to use “reads” clause to read array of sequences in Dafny?

Tags: arrays, dafny

In my code implementation I have a array of sequences with tuple elements (int, string), which `int` represents a key and `string` a value.

I am trying to accomplish the following verification "There must not be any duplicate key across all elements present in array buckets".

I have the following code, but I am having problems on reading the sequence elements.

```
var buckets:array<seq<(int, string)>>;

function Valid():bool 
    reads `buckets //set x | x in buckets[..] Broken attempt that tries to read the elements
{ 
    buckets.Length > 0 
    // Some code just to try to read the sequence elements
    // && forall i :: 0 <= i < buckets.Length ==> forall j :: 0 <= j < |buckets[i]| ==> buckets[i][j].0 != buckets[i][j].0
}
```

Any tips on how can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A function needs to declare the set of objects whose state it reads. An array is an object. I'm assuming your code snippet above sits inside a class.

- Your function reads the `buckets` field of `this`, so you need to include `this` 
  in the `reads` clause.

  You have done this in an advanced way, which says that 
  the function depends on `this`, but only on the `buckets` field of `this`. If you really need that precision, you're doing that correctly. If you don't need that precision, my suggestion would be to replace

  ```
  reads `buckets
  ```

  with

  ```
  reads this
  ```
- Your function reads the `Length` field of `this.buckets`. However, `Length` is a readonly field, so you don't need to list `this.buckets` in the read frame.
- Your function reads `buckets[i]`. That is, it reads element `i` of `this.buckets`. Therefore, you must include `this.buckets` in your `reads` clause.

So, do this:

```
reads this, buckets
```

and your function will verify.